# PHP: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error while adding this code. Would appreciate some help. It's for a CS jackpot site.

```
$sitename = "website.com"; // YOUR DOMAIN
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "db_pass"); // MYSQL , LOCALHOOST , USERNAME , PASSWORD 
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $link); // MYSQL DATABASE
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue) {
    if($finder == "1") $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");
    else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        return $row[$rowname];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: shouldn't $query be $result?

Comment: `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`, not `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))`

Comment: still getting the error, now with "boolean give"

Comment: Which suggests that the query failed. Echo out the query that it is trying to execute and hopefully we can see the error in it.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- Use **mysqli** better than mysql
- Split the vars in the query, like "SELECT ".$rowname." FROM ".$tablename;

Comment: I have no idea how to translate this into mysqli:

`function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue) {
    if($finder == "1") $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");
    else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        return $row[$rowname];`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help...

```
<?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','username','password','database_name');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//MySqli Select Query
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, product_name FROM products");

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["id"].' - '.$row["product_name"].'<br>';
}  

$results->free();
$mysqli->close();
```